Calculating Postfix in c
I have been asked to calculate a postfix expression , which means that for every consequtive 2 numbers there is an arithmetical operation  in between , for example fot the given string "123*+" the result will be 7 --> 1+(2*3)
I tried to write the code in C but for some reason i get that the result is 0
can someone tell me why? or if my direction is wrong?
And how can i return to the user that there was an error with the given string such as uknown char or empty string  if the function needs to return an int. I can't return NULL right.?
thank you
#include <stdio.h>
#define ERROR -2147483648
int Postfix(char *str) {
    if(!str)
        return ERROR;
    int str_length;
    for ( str_length = 0;str[str_length]!='\0'; str_length++); // calculating the exact number of chars in the string
    int mid=str_length/2;// the length of the string will always be odd because its not possible that the number of digits equals to the number of arithmetics puncuation sice for every artihmetic
    //puncutation there are 2 digits.
    int *current, *prev, result=0;

    char *arithmetic;
    arithmetic=str+mid+2;// address of the first arithemetic sign in the array

    prev=str+mid;// address of the  second last digit in the array

    current=str+mid+1; // address of the last digit in the array

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) { // the loop will run the exact number of arithmetic operations
        prev=str+mid-i;
        arithmetic=str+mid+i;
        switch(*arithmetic) {
            case '+': {
                result+=(*current)+(*prev);
                break;
            }
            case '-': {
                result+=(*current)-(*prev);
                break;
            }
            case '*': {
                result+=(*current)*(*prev);
                break;
            }
            case '/': { // need to handle the case with division by 0?
                result+=(*current)/(*prev);
                break;
            }
            default: { // need to handle the case where an arithmetic which is not (+,-,*,/) was inserted?
                result+=0;
                break;
            }

        }
        *current=result;
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
char c[]="231*+";
int result=Postfix(&c);
    printf("%d",result);
    if(result!=ERROR)
        printf("The result is: %d",result);
    else
        printf("An error occured.");
return 0;
}


Please run your code through and automatic formatting tool. Not only does it make the code easier to read for people here, it also then follows the structure and thus helps you find glitches. Also, start with a human language description of what you're doing and keep that as comment in your code. Further, compile with warnings enabled, which may already give you lots of hints. Lastly, extract a [mcve] to help you help yourself.

You typically use a stack to evaluate RPN. As you traverse the input, if something is an operand, you push it on the stack. If it's an operator, you pop the appropriate number of items from the stack, carry out that operation on them, and push the result back on the stack.
When you're done, you expect the stack to contain one item, which will be the result.
As far as how to signal an error: there are multiple possibilities, none of them exactly perfect. For one possibility, instead of returning the result value, you can pass in a pointer to where the function should write the result, and have it return a Boolean value to signal whether it succeeded. But that's certainly not the only way you can do things.

There are several issues:

Postfix expects a char *, but you provided it &c, which is char **, so this is already going wrong from the very start.

You define int *current, *prev, but then use them as char *

First you initialise arithmetic=str+mid+2, taking 2 bytes as additional offset. Not only is this bad practice, but then in the for loop you increment arithmetic with steps of 1 byte, and by consequence you read characters at half-way offsets. You should just use array index notation.

Your code and comments assume that all operators are in the second half of the input string. This is not necessarily so. For example, 12+3*4- is a valid postfix expression. So your algorithm based on mid and other related variables is wrong.


Postfix notation can be evaluated using a stack: whenever you read a number, you put it on the stack, and whenever you read an operator you take the two top stack elements as operands of the operation, perform it, and store the result back on the stack. At the end the stack has the result.
Here is how that would be done. A lot of your code had to be replaced:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ERROR INT_MIN

int Postfix(char *str) {
    if (!str) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    int *stack = malloc(sizeof(int*) * len);
    size_t stack_size = 0;

    int last = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; last != ERROR && i < len; i++) {
        char ch = str[i];
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            // Stack digit
            stack[stack_size++] = ch - '0';
        } else if (stack_size < 2) {
            // Missing operands
            last = ERROR;
        } else {
            // Pop two operands
            int b = stack[--stack_size];
            int a = stack[--stack_size];
            // Perform operation
            last =  ch == '+' ? a + b
                  : ch == '-' ? a - b
                  : ch == '*' ? a * b
                  : ch == '/' ? a / b
                  : ERROR;
            // Stack result
            stack[stack_size++] = last;
        }
    }
    int result = last == ERROR || stack_size != 1 ? ERROR : stack[0];
    free(stack);
    return result;
}

Binary operators
In your question you speak of binary operators ("for every consequtive 2 numbers there is an arithmetical operation"). If ever you want to cope with unary or -ary operators, then you'll need to adapt how many operands you'll pop from the stack. If the operator is unary, you pop one operand from the stack, ...etc.

It would be better to use size_t for len.

True. Have updated.

"[...] whenever you read an operator you take the two top stack elements as operands of the operation, perform it, and store the result back on the stack." This is correct only if you restrict yourself to binary operators.

Yes, @Jerry. That is a given in the OP.

@trincot: no, not really. The operators shown happen to be binary, but that doesn't seem to be a requirement (and certainly isn't in general).

It certainly isn't in general, but OP wrote "consequtive [sic] 2 numbers there is an arithmetical operation", which I took as specification of which type of operators they work with (i.e. binary). It would of course be no problem to extend this to unary and other operators, but I didn't get the impression that is what the asker is looking for.

Anyway, I added a paragraph to my answer to express that.

-2147483648 results in the wrong type long/long long which is later implicitly converted back to int in an implementation-defined manner. Consider using #define ERROR (-2147483647 - 1) instead. And that part would be a FAQ, which I'm sure we have several posts about.

Ah, didn't realise that, @Lundin! Have updated.
